# Полноэкранная галерея через фрагменты

Tags: android, android-fragment

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь написать просмотр фотографий размером на весь экран через фрагменты.
Столкнулся с ситуацией что при выборе в GridView первой картинки - не срабатывает строка `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page, false);`. Фотографию можно лишь увидеть, перейдя на следующую, а затем вернувшись, на первую. В этом случае, работает `public void onPageSelected(int p1)`.
Кто сталкивался с подобной ситуацией и, возможно знает, какой-либо костыль?

**ImageViewPager.java**

```
public class ImageViewPager extends FragmentActivity {

int page;
ViewPager mViewPager;
ImagePagerA mPagerAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    this.page = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

    mPagerAdapter = new ImagePagerA(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int p1, float p2, int p3) {
            // TODO: Implement this method
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int p1) {
            ImageShowFragment fragment = (ImageShowFragment) mPagerAdapter.getItem(p1);
            fragment.showImage(Zakazchik_full.imagesArray[p1]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int p1) {
            // TODO: Implement this method
        }

    });

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page, false); // при открытие фрагмента, не работает

}
}
```

**ДОБАВЛЕНО:**
Первую картинку опять не показывает, а при попытке перелистать на следующую либо при выборе любой (не первой) - ругается:

```
public class ImageShowFragment extends Fragment {

private ImageView imageView;
private FrameLayout fl_loading_gallery_new;
private RelativeLayout full_screen_gallery_layout_new;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    full_screen_gallery_layout_new = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.full_screen_gallery_layout_new);
    fl_loading_gallery_new = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fl_loading_gallery_new);
    imageView = new ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

    return imageView;
}

public void showImage(String url) {

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            full_screen_gallery_layout_new.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fl_loading_gallery_new.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            fl_loading_gallery_new.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            full_screen_gallery_layout_new.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            fl_loading_gallery_new.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            full_screen_gallery_layout_new.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

}

}
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
full_screen_gallery_layout_new.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**ДОБАВЛЕНО**
**view_pager.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff000000">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fl_loading_gallery_new"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gallery_layout"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar5"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/full_screen_gallery_layout_new"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

FrameLayout fl_loading_gallery_new расположен выше уровнем и в нем показывается прогрессбар

RelativeLayout full_screen_gallery_layout_new - ниже уровнем и в нём непосредственно показывается картинка.

Comment: попробуйте так:    
    

    mViewPager.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page, false);
        }
    })

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что вы устанавливаете значение переменной слишком рано, когда getActivity() равно null.
Это происходит потому что класс фрагмента инициализируется до прикрепления к активити, вам нужно объявление переменной сделать в методе onCreateView.

```
public class ImageShowFragment extends Fragment {

private ImageView imageView;
final FrameLayout fl_loading_gallery_new;
final RelativeLayout full_screen_gallery_layout_new;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    imageView = new ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

    fl_loading_gallery_new = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fl_loading_gallery_new);
    full_screen_gallery_layout_new = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.full_screen_gallery_layout_new);

    return imageView;
}
```

P.S.: Возможно не будет работать с final, тогда просто используйте private.

Comment: Исправил.
Первую фотографию так же не показывает, и при перелистывании на вторую либо при выборе любой другой - ругается на строчку full_screen_gallery_layout_new.setVisibility(View.GONE); (NullPointerException)

Comment: А у вас элемент full_screen_gallery_layout_new находится во фрагменте или в активити?

Comment: Так же, что вы передаете в "id"? Возможно там некорректное значение. Тут id - это не ID элемента, а номер фрагмента в ViewPager, начиная с 0.

Comment: Элемент находится в активити. В id передается 0 при нажатии на первую фотографию.